# How can I auto format code to fit into 120 character max line in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a codebase I need to re-format with certain rules

1. 120 characters max per line
2. No white spaces at end
3. remove unnecessary spaces in brackets and braces
4. change tabs to spaces
   etc.

I am working in Visual Studio Professional 2019, but I can load the code in any other editor that can do the formatting, like VSCode.

There are thousands of lines of code, and none of this needs to be done manually by hand.
I am looking steps or instructions on how to automatically do this within visual studio, it is not very clear how to do it from the menu options.

The code is in C#

Thank you,

Comment: ReSharper seems to do what you want

Comment: Consider ignoring rule 1. Automatic line wrapping of source code seldomly gives a reasonable result. A developer should decide when lines should be wrapped and where.